# scala dealing with large (mongodb) resultsets

Tags: mongodb, scala

i have a general question regarding MongoDB Results: Lets say i have a trillion results that i'd like to split up using the Casbah driver I still seem to get OutOfMemoryErrors even using the limit command. Is there a general advice on how to handle huge resultsets apart from splitting them up by using limit and hitting the next page lazily?

Or could one even use views in a fashion to handle this process easily?

Is there some kind of magick trick to make it a bit easier?

regards,

Stefan

Comment: Could you provide an insight in how you are querying and iterating the resultset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

it's not a direct solution but the problem with large cursors in general terms is that they will become IO bound eventually.

So i added the ability to page the results in the application:

to cycle between the results (forwards and backwards) I use the following methods:

```
def findPagesWithGreaterId(pageid: String, limit: Int): List[Page] =

      findAsListSortedLimit(MongoDBObject("_id" -> MongoDBObject("$gt" -> new ObjectId(pageid))), MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1), limit) 

  /**
   * finds a slice of pages with a smaller id (required for paging)
   */
  def findPagesWithSmallerId(pageid: String, limit: Int): List[Page] = 

findAsListSortedLimit(MongoDBObject("_id" -> MongoDBObject("$lt" -> new ObjectId(pageid))), MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1), limit)

      /**
```

So, no matter what you do you should be restricting the cursor size in the 1st place since a large cursor will always end up in a bad performance.

This is of course not the elgant solution that I wanted to have.